# Keep getting a Segmentation fault: 11

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// A Tree node
typedef struct leaf
{
    char ch;
    int freq;
    struct leaf *left, *right;
}leaf;

typedef struct node{
    int data;
    leaf* leaf_data;
    struct node *ptr;
} node;

//----- LINKED LIST -----
struct LinkedList {
   node* head;
   //node* tail;
};
typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList_s;


leaf* createLeaf(char ch, int freq)
{
    leaf* node = malloc(sizeof(leaf));

    node->ch = ch;
    node->freq = freq;
    node->left = NULL;
    node->right= NULL;
    return node;
}

//----- CREATE LINKED LIST -----
LinkedList_s createSortedList()
{
   LinkedList_s list = {NULL};
   return list;
}

node* createStackNode(leaf* l){
    node* temp = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node)) ;
    temp->data = (int) l->freq;

    temp->leaf_data = l;

    return temp;
}


void insert(LinkedList_s* head, node* l) {
    

    if(head->head == NULL){
        head->head = l;
    }
    else if (head->head->data > l->data){
        l->ptr = head->head;
        head->head = l;
    }
    else{
    node *prev = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    int i = 0;

    prev = NULL;
    next = head->head;
    while(next != NULL && i == 0){
       
        if (next->data >= l->data){
            prev->ptr = l;
            l->ptr = next;
            i = 1;
        }
        prev = next;
        next = next->ptr;
    }
    if (next == NULL){
        prev->ptr = l;
        l->ptr = next;
    }
   
    
    }

}


node* dequeue(LinkedList_s *list){
    node* temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    temp = list->head;
    list->head = list->head->ptr;

    return temp;
}

void insertLeaf(LinkedList_s *list, leaf* l){
    node* n = createStackNode(l);
    //printf("%d", n->data);
    insert(list, n);
}
```

basically I'm building a huffman encoder for a class project and I'm trying to create a sorted list/priority queue to store BTS leaf node in order of frequency. I'm having problems with createStackNode. If I change the node struct int data to int* data I don't get a seg. fault, but this way it randomly seg. faults and won't sort. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

So I call insertLeft from a separate file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "Sorted_List.h"
#include "linked_counter.h"


int main(void){
    //Make a Frequency List
    LinkedList_t* x = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList_t));
    x = makeList();

    //Create a Sorted List/Priority Queue
    struct LinkedList_s* list = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList_s));
    *list = createSortedList();
    leaf* l = malloc(sizeof(leaf));

    //Current node for traversal 
    Node_t* current = malloc(sizeof(Node_t));
    current= x->head;
    
    
    while(current != NULL){

        l = createLeaf(current->data, current->count);
        printf("%c %d  ->",l->ch, l->freq);
        insertLeaf(list, l);

        current= current->next;
    }

    //for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        //printf("%c~~\n", list->head->leaf_data->ch);
}
```

at insert leaf it gives the fault

Comment: Run the code using a debugger. It will halt when the fault is encountered. You can back trace from there and examine the conditions which caused the fault to happen.

Comment: Your insert is extremely complicated. An insert function that takes a prepared node requires two lines.

Comment: Here is an example of a linked list implementation that can take any type of data. Look how clean and simplistic it is: https://pastebin.com/gqEnBxG9

Comment: The first thing that `main` does is call `malloc`, storing the result in `x`.  The second thing it does is call `makeList`, assignint the result to `x` and discarding the value that `malloc` returned.  So (1) the call to `malloc` is useless, and (2) it's a memory leak (a bug).

Comment: The same but occurs shortly below, with `current`.  Hint:  `x = foo(); x = y;` is equivalent to `(void) foo(); x = y;`.  In other words, the result of the call to `foo` is lost.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys! it ended up being in the insert function previous = NULL; didn't even notice but it was the main cause of seg faults